# Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mouse

I am using a Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 on a Mac Book Pro (ironic?).

I am very happy with it.

Whenever I go to **WIN7** (using Bootcamp) I have extra functionality on it. For example, the *back-left* button (not regular left button) to go back on browser history.

My question is: Is there a way to achieve similar functionality on Mac OS X? Is there a Microsoft specific driver for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's official drivers are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=MK), but there is no entry for a Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000.

If you don't mind the price tag, I would check out [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/).